# How to test the binding of configuration properties in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing

I have a Spring Boot Application with the following (simplified) configuration class

```java
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "prefix")
@Configuration
public class ConfigProperties {
    @NotNull
    public Duration snapshotOffset;

}
```

My code is working, but I would like know how I can write unit tests for the binding process with different property files as input?

Answer (score 1):

You can configure test properties files by using the `locations` or `value` attribute of the [`TestPropertySource`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/TestPropertySource.html) annotation :

```
//Typically, @TestPropertySource will be used in conjunction with @ContextConfiguration.
@ContextConfiguration
@TestPropertySource("/test.properties") 
public class Test {
    // class body...
}
```

Comment: I was looking for a solution like a real unit test with a kind of try-catch-statement.

Comment: @Oliver I am not sure to understand , could you give me a scenario example ?